# Actionscript: loader not found

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

I am trying to load an image onto my stage. I use the following code:

```
    public function loadImg():void{

        var iLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        iLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressStatus);
        iLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderReady);

        var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(imgPath+'testimg.JPG');
        iLoader.load(fileRequest);

    }

    public function onProgressStatus(e:ProgressEvent) {   
        trace(e.bytesLoaded, e.bytesTotal); 
    }

    public function onLoaderReady(e:Event) {     
        this.stage.addChild(iLoader); // error is here
    }
```

However it seems that iLoader is not found in onLoaderReady:

```
1120: Access of undefined property iLoader.
```

How do I pass object iLoader to this function? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this page on Function scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f54.html). Variables defined inside a function are only available within it, so you just need to define them outside of the function:

```
private var iLoader:Loader;

public function loadImg():void{

    iLoader = new Loader();
    //...

}
```

Comment: Now I got another error:
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. // at gallery/onLoaderReady()" Stage isn't found I believe this means? To use stage in my class I put the following code in my class: 

`function gallery()
  {
   this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
  }

  private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {
   this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
   sayStage();
  }

     public function sayStage():void {
   trace(stage);
  }`

in which gallery is the constructor.

Comment: You're right, that suggests `stage` can't be found. Maybe your `loadImg()` function is called before `gallery` is added to the stage?

Comment: Isn't the constructor (gallery) called first always?

Comment: Yes, but the event is asynchronous. If you do something like `var gallery:Gallery = new Gallery(); gallery.loadImg(); addChild(gallery)`, that could produce this error. Are you definitely adding `gallery` to the stage first? If you add your code which creates `gallery` to your question, we can check that too.

Comment: I think this is a different problem (since calling stage is the problem here i suppose?). The whole class can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537410/add-loader-to-stage-from-class

Comment: Just looking quickly, I think you're exactly right. The "display tree" in AS is a special data structure which isn't very clear from the documentation. As some people have said in your other question, `stage` is null until an object is added to the display. `DisplayObjects` in AS3 have several properties like `stage` and `parent`, which are populated automatically when they're added to the display tree. Until you run `addChild()`, they will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code, it looks like `iLoader` is a variable scoped to the function `loadImg`.  You can't access it by that name outside of loadImg.

One workaround is to put your declaration of iLoader in a broader scope.  In this case, that would be outside of all the functions, as David Mear suggests.

However, you should be able to get around it in a more graceful way.  Every event in AS3 has a target property.  In this case, the target should be your loader.  So inside `onLoaderReady`, you should be able to do the following:

```
 this.stage.addChild(e.target);
```

There's a chance this may not work - since the loader is no longer in scope, it may be deleted.  I believe it will stick around long enough for this line of code to succeed, but don't have any way of testing right now.  If you try it and it fails, we'll just go with David's answer and I'll delete mine.